# Algebraic group extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (Milne's AG, Exercise 2.6)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology

This is exercise 2.6 in Milne's "Algebraic Groups". It asks to show that the commutative algebraic group extensions over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$

$$0\to\mu_p\to G\to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

are classified by the group $k^×/k^{×p}$. However, I am stuck at deciphering what $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is in this context? My first guess was that it's the constant algebraic group corresponding to the abstract group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but this doesn't seem to give the right answer.

The extensions should be classified by $H^1_{flat}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\mu_p)$, which should be calculated by the complex

$Hom_k(k[T]/(T^p-1),\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}k)\to Hom_k(k[T]/(T^p-1),\prod_{i,j\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}k)\to Hom_k(k[T]/(T^p-1),\prod_{i,j,l\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}k),$
which doesn't give the 'correct' answer. Did I guess wrong, and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ means something else in this context?

Comment: What do you mean by $Hom_k$ ? I mean, this is not simply the homomorphisms of $k$-algebra as you need to take into account the group structures of $\mu_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Roland Do I? Shouldn't these be just all morphisms of $k$-algebras?

Comment: Of course $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ isn't just $p$ points. It is a group and a group extension should take into account the group structure. If you take only the $k$-algebra structure of $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}k$, this means that you have completely forgotten the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and this cannot be the right thing to do.

Comment: I haven't forgotten it. It induces a group structure on the $Hom_k$ sets. One of the definitions of a group object says that $Z$ is a group object if the sets $Hom(X,Z)$ have a group structure, but the $Hom$ itself is taken inside the ambient category, not in some category of group objects.

Comment: It is indeed the constant group scheme. To solve the exercise, you can use the Kummer sequence. I am not sure what your complex is supposed to compute or why